# Ansible: curl from ansible playbook failed, but from the remote host itself success

Tags: curl, ansible

I want to do some curl on ansible playbook, but it always fail. But when i do curl to the remote host itself, it success.

I have tried:

1. using ansible uri module
2. shell module (raw shell bash)
3. and the current one is, i use shell module to create executeable .sh that do the curl, and then execute it.

None of them work.

This is my current code:

```
- name: Write script to insert dummy data
  become_user: root
  shell: |
        echo "curl {{'http://localhost:8080/insetdummydata'}}" > "/home/ubuntu/insert.txt"

- name: Make script executable
  become_user: root
  shell: chmod +x /home/ubuntu/wildduck/insert.sh

- name: Execute script to insert dummy data
  become_user: root
  shell: /home/ubuntu/wildduck/insert.sh
```

The output should print the response on the console, but it fail with status connection refused.
[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFiAi.png)

I have mention above that if i do curl on the remote machine itself, the command is works. The output should print the response of the request. 
[This is the output when i do the curl from remote host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR5pv.png).

Did i miss something on configuring the playbook?

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Just add it inline. Also, Is that actually the playbook generating the error? The syntax for using the URL as a variable is strange. Can you change the shell command to just `curl http://localhost:8080/insetdummydata` and post the output of playbook run with `-vvv` for debug output?

Answer (score 0):

To download a file from a web server use:

```
- name: Download foo.conf
  get_url:
    url: http://localhost:8080/insetdummydata
    dest: /home/ubuntu/insert.txt
    mode: '0440'
```

But could you describe what you want to do instead of whats going wrong?